# SQL LEFT JOIN in history table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I prepared an sqlFiddle, located here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/951c1/2/1

I have 3 tables (cars, colors, and car_color_history). In `colors` there are the colors with some kind of metadata I am interested in. In `cars`, there are a bunch of cars with a 'wanted_color' key which tells the car to change to the given color. In `car_color_history`, there are all the entries, on what specific time a car had what color.

What I want now is a view/select statement, to get all cars with the **current** and the **wanted** color information.

My first idea was to do this with left joins and some kind of GROUP BY magic, but up until now, I could not get that to work

A working solution is the second select in the fiddle with subselects. Am I correct that that is not a pretty solution as it is slow? Plus i do have to provide the subselect for each displayed column :(

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using left Joins? All cars should have a color, shouldn't they? Inner Joins will improve your performance

Comment: The numeric keys should really be `integer`, not `varchar`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter true, but i did use the int keys just in this simplified example. In my real world application, the keys are strings :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1c371/2)

```
select
    ca.carkey,
    description,
    cow.other_info as wanted_color,
    cco.other_info as current_color,
    cch.datetime as current_color_datetime
from
    cars ca
    left join
    colors cow on ca.wanted_color = cow.colorkey
    left join (
        select distinct on (carkey) *
        from car_color_history
        order by carkey, datetime desc
    ) cch using(carkey)
    left join
    colors cco on cch.colorkey = cco.colorkey
```